# Java: compare two object lists

Tags: java, list, object

I'm trying to compare two lists of same objects, those two lists are `nodes_cc` and `nodes_volume`. They contains several `Node` objects. A `Node is` defined by `ID` and `VALUE`. The nodes on the two lists can have common IDs but not common values.

I want to compare the lists like this: I control the first list list (`nodes_cc`) , if I meet a node that doesn't appear on the second list (`nodes_volume`), the control MUST stop, even if I will find other nodes that belong even to the second list. I was thinking to use a break so I tried this:

```
 int count=0;

for (int i=0;i<cc_nodes.size();i++){
    Node node = cc_nodes.get(i);
    for(int j=0;j<volume_nodes.size();j++){       
      Node node2 = volume_nodes.get(j);
        if (node.id==node2.id){
            count++;                      
        }
        else {
            break;         
        }       
    } 
}
```

The problem is: the for cycle breaks only after the first check (count is 1), where i'm doing wrong? Can you help fix me this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use some boolean, and check it after your inner `for` loop :

```
 int count=0;

    for (int i=0;i<cc_nodes.size();i++){

        Node node = cc_nodes.get(i);
        boolean found = false;

        for(int j=0;j<volume_nodes.size();j++){       
          Node node2 = volume_nodes.get(j);
            if (node.id==node2.id){
                count++; 
                found = true;           
            }

        } 

        if(!found)
          break;    

    }
```

Comment: Thc but it doesen't works, the for still stop after 1 step ç_ç

Comment: What is the type of the "id" of a Node ?

Comment: Seems that it doesen't like the if with equals, i met the error "int cannot be dereferenced"

Comment: Id are INT , values are double.

Comment: Well okay, you should try to add print statements into the loops, with the id of Node A, and the id of Node b, to understand what happens.

Comment: Already done, it print me only the first confront X - X (X - X are nodes on common of the two lists). seems that he check the first 2 nodes, then he stop instead continue. If i remove the break, it check ALL the nodes of the first list, opposite problem

Comment: Could you write the Nodes you have in the lists ?

Comment: Well the cc list has 4k nodes, the second only 20. The first is like this (id + value):                                                                                                      1 0.47158677
9 0.43341145
6 0.430271204
2 0.415762091

Comment: Second list: 1 21894.0
9 20745.0
2 20682.0
6 20648.0
3 20348.0

Comment: Okay maybe better: [ 1 0.47158677 ]
[ 9 0.43341145 ]
[ 6 0.430271204 ]
[ 2 0.415762091 ] and [ 1 21894.0 ]
[ 9 20745.0 ]
[ 2 20682.0 ]
[ 6 20648.0 ]
[ 3 20348.0 ]

Answer (score 0):

You can Override .equals() and .hashcode() method in Node object to use id as comparator  and then :

```
int count=0;

for (Node node : cc_nodes){
    if(volume_nodes.contains(node))
      count++;
    else 
      break;
}
```

You can add this in Node object (if id is int value)

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + id;
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Node other = (Node) obj;
    if (id != other.id)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I can't use contains because the two lists can have nodes with common ID but not common VALUES. The nodes of first list have all int as values while the second have all double as value. So, contains will always return false.

Comment: unless you override equals value in your node object